# AJAX loaded content use .ON or add the script in the ajax request page?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a `view more` option in my website `index` page that I load using a AJAX.
this will bring more content to user from `page_ajax.php`.

The problem is this `DOM` content need a JQUERY click event.

`<span class=productinfo>product info</span>`

My question is, where should I add the `<script>` tag? in the `index.php` page or in the `page_ajax.php` (that will load jquery in each call)?

If I add in index.php jquery will not work, should I add the script tag in page_ajax.php? or **should I use .ON** in index jquery? how would it be? Can someone give me an example?

```
<script>
$(function() {
$(".productinfo").click(function(){

var element = $(this);
var I = element.attr("data-id");
var info = 'id=' + I;

 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   cache: false,
   url: "/product.php",
   dataType: "json",
   data: info,

  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }

 });
return false;
});
});
<script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those elements are dynamically loaded so jQuery doesn't know about them when it delegates that handler.

So you'd have to delegate the event to a parent like this:

```
$( document.body ).on('click', '.productinfo' , function(e){

    var element = $(this);
    var I = element.attr("data-id");
    var info = 'id=' + I;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "/product.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: info,

        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }

    });

    return false;

});
```

Comment: thank you! what is this document.body? is the same as $(function() { ?

Comment: @RickJoe Sorry for the late reply. What happens is that you assign a click event to the whole document and then you "filter" it with that `.productinfo` selector. So whenever you click on your page, it will check if it's a `.productinfo` element and it will execute the callback.